# How we can detect the android device as beacon in iOS Application

Tags: android, ios, ibeacon, altbeacon, beacon

I make a android device as beacon transmitter using Altbeacon api.
I want to scan that beacon using the ios Application using the iBeacon or Altbeacon Api code. But  I am not able to find that beacon. Please Help for the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: As per `Altbeacon` implementation or sdk is not available on iOS

Comment: Have you tried this https://github.com/AltBeacon/ios-beacon-tools ?

Comment: https://github.com/Decemberlabs/AltBeacon

Comment: Paulw11 Great its working for android device. But it can work for ibeacon for ios device?

Comment: How we can use this as iPhone device as beacon transmitter.

Answer (score 3):

How you detect an Android beacon transmitter on iOS depends on the format of the beacon you are using in the transmission.  The Android Beacon Library supports transmitting these formats:

1. iBeacon
2. AltBeacon
3. Eddystone-UID, Eddystone-URL and Eddystone-EID

Only the first of the three formats above can be detected on iOS by its built-in CoreLocation APIs.  The other three can be detected by this toolkit: https://github.com/AltBeacon/ios-beacon-tools or by Google's beacon SDKs.

You might try using the [Beacon Scope app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/beacon-scope/id1315448039?platform=iphone) for iOS to detect your Android transmitter, as it uses CoreLocation and the iOS Beacon Tools behind the scenes.  If this works, you should be able to make your code work, too.

Comment: I used the AltBeacon and Eddystone as transmitter with android device, both can detect by iphone device after using the **bold** 'CBCentralManager' class and its delegate. Its can not able to detect in suspending and terminate state of ios application. can you help how we can make as ibeacon transmitter to detect in terminate state of application. Please tell which device beacon device in market is come as ibeacon transmitter. we need to get beacon packet in terminate state of application. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, iOS has no support for CoreBluetooth detecting beacons or other bluetooth transmissions in the terminated state.  You can only do that with the iBeacon format using CoreLocation.